# Android UDP peer to peer networking communication (without server)

Tags: android, sockets, udp, datagram

I am new in Android networking and working on project p2p without server.

Initially I have to do communication between 2 devices. I achieved successful communication between two wifi networks within and behind different NATS via DataGramSocket with port forwarding via Upnp using [library](https://github.com/4thline/cling).

The problem i am facing is while communication between Mobile network and my wifi network or between 2 mobile network. When i send message from mobile network I am unable to receive it in my app but can listen on same port in NetCat app.

Anyone can help me in this regard?

**Sending**

```
try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(dstPort);
        address = InetAddress.getByName(dstAddress);
        socket.connect(address,dstPort);
        socket.setBroadcast(false);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        //sendState("Socket Status "+socket.isConnected());
        String sendString = msg;
        byte[] sendData = sendString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,
                address, dstPort);
        socket.send(sendPacket);
        //sendState("Sent = "+sendData);

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        //sendState(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        sendState("SocketException");
    }
```

**Receiving**

```
try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(dstPort);
            address = InetAddress.getByName(dstAddress);
            // send request
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            DatagramPacket packet =
                    new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, dstPort);
            socket.connect(address,dstPort);
            socket.setBroadcast(false);
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket.receive(packet);
            String line = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            sendState(line);
            //sendState("Reached3");


        } catch (SocketException e) {
            //sendState(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            sendState("SocketException");
        }
```

**Port Forwarding via UpNp**

```
   protected void setUpnp(int port_)
{
    if(Connectivity.isConnectedWifi(this)) {
        String myIp = getIpAddress();
        int port = port_;

        //creates a port mapping configuration with the external/internal port, an internal host IP, the protocol and an optional description
        PortMapping[] desiredMapping = new PortMapping[2];
        desiredMapping[0] = new PortMapping(port, myIp, PortMapping.Protocol.TCP);
        desiredMapping[1] = new PortMapping(port, myIp, PortMapping.Protocol.UDP);

        //starting the UPnP service
        UpnpService upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl(new AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration());
        RegistryListener registryListener = new PortMappingListener(desiredMapping);
        upnpService.getRegistry().addListener(registryListener);
        upnpService.getControlPoint().search();
    }
    else if(Connectivity.isConnectedMobile(this))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the code here seems fine there are a couple problems with your approach.

1. Most mobile networks [do not support UPnP port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291759/upnp-nat-traversal-for-3g-4g-wireless-data-connection-on-android).
2. Depending on your network topology (which you can't always control) there might be two or more layers of NAT routing behind your public-facing address. The closest layer might support UPnP, but other layers might not.

Instead of UPnP, you might want to try the **UDP hole punching technique** for NAT traversal explained [here](https://www.zerotier.com/blog/state-of-nat-traversal.shtml) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128).

While it requires a publicly available server to coordinate 'peer introduction', this technique is far more widely supported ([92-96% of peers](https://www.zerotier.com/blog/state-of-nat-traversal.shtml)) in today's highly fragmented internet than other techniques such as UPnP port forwarding, particularly when dealing with mobile networks or multiple layers of NAT routing.

It basically boils down to UDP being a connectionless protocol (unlike TCP), so when two peers (behind NAT routers) send a UDP message to each other *simultaneously*, their respective NAT routers are 'tricked' into believing the inbound request from the other peer is a response to the original outgoing packet.

Besides, if you are concerned about the cost of running a server, these days you can get many years of free cloud VM server usage if you rotate membership among the main cloud vendors (AWS, Microsoft, Google, AliCloud..).